# How to fix `LoadError: unrecognized HDF5 datatype class 4` using Julia's JLD to store data from Eirene package?

Tags: julia, hdf5, topology

I am trying to save a large variable in Julia resulting from a long computation as a file, so I can load the variable later on without recomputing it. When I load the variable I get an exception. I'm storing the file using the JLD library for Julia. I compute the variable using the library Eirene, which performs topological data analysis. The resulting file is 173MB.

I've looked this up and I couldn't find anything about this error message online. I was worried at first that the file was corrupted or something due to insufficient space but that's not the case.

This is the offending code:

```
using Eirene
using JLD

C = load("/path_to_file/file.jld")["filtration"]
```

And here is the code where I save the file:

```
using Eirene
using JLD

C = eirene("/path_to_distance_matrix/dmat",maxdim=3)
save("/path_to_file/file.jld", "filtration", C)
```

`eirene` basically builds a series of triangular structures based on the distances between points in a distance matrix I give it. The distance matrix in particular is very dense, causing a long triangle-building calculation. 
You can access the distance matrix [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/lachrimae/0a34b28f36ee0734818af487125c4ed0) if you want to reproduce this problem. The calculation takes me 30min on my laptop.

I get the following error message (the file `get_class_reps` is the one that contains the first code snippet above).

```
ERROR: LoadError: unrecognized HDF5 datatype class 4
Stacktrace:
 [1] jldatatype(::JLD.JldFile, ::HDF5.HDF5Datatype) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/jld_types.jl:738
 [2] read(::JLD.JldDataset) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:370
 [3] read_ref(::JLD.JldFile, ::HDF5.HDF5ReferenceObj) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:502
 [4] read_refs(::JLD.JldDataset, ::Type{Any}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Tuple{Int64}) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:475
 [5] read_array(::JLD.JldDataset, ::HDF5.HDF5Datatype, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Tuple{Int64}) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:409
 [6] read_array(::JLD.JldDataset, ::HDF5.HDF5Datatype, ::Int64, ::Int64) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:408
 [7] read(::JLD.JldDataset) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:372
 [8] read_ref(::JLD.JldFile, ::HDF5.HDF5ReferenceObj) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:502
 [9] jlconvert(::Type{JLD.AssociativeWrapper{String,Any,Dict{String,Any}}}, ::JLD.JldFile, ::Ptr{UInt8}) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/jld_types.jl:434
 [10] read_scalar(::JLD.JldDataset, ::HDF5.HDF5Datatype, ::Type) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:398
 [11] read(::JLD.JldDataset) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:370
 [12] read_ref(::JLD.JldFile, ::HDF5.HDF5ReferenceObj) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:502
 [13] read_refs(::JLD.JldDataset, ::Type{Any}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Tuple{Int64}) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:475
 [14] read_array(::JLD.JldDataset, ::HDF5.HDF5Datatype, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Tuple{Int64}) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:409
 [15] read_array(::JLD.JldDataset, ::HDF5.HDF5Datatype, ::Int64, ::Int64) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:408
 [16] read(::JLD.JldDataset) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:372
 [17] read_ref(::JLD.JldFile, ::HDF5.HDF5ReferenceObj) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:502
 [18] jlconvert(::Type{JLD.AssociativeWrapper{String,Any,Dict{String,Any}}}, ::JLD.JldFile, ::Ptr{UInt8}) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/jld_types.jl:434
 [19] read_scalar(::JLD.JldDataset, ::HDF5.HDF5Datatype, ::Type) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:398
 [20] read(::JLD.JldDataset) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:370
 [21] read(::JLD.JldFile, ::String) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:346
 [22] #39 at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [23] iterate at ./generator.jl:47 [inlined]
 [24] collect(::Base.Generator{Array{String,1},getfield(JLD, Symbol("##39#41")){JLD.JldFile}}) at ./array.jl:606
 [25] (::getfield(JLD, Symbol("##38#40")))(::JLD.JldFile) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:1234
 [26] #jldopen#14(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::getfield(JLD, Symbol("##38#40")), ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:246
 [27] load at /home/curran/.julia/packages/JLD/1BoSz/src/JLD.jl:244 [inlined]
 [28] #load#13(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::String) at /home/curran/.julia/packages/FileIO/e8FNK/src/loadsave.jl:118
 [29] load at /home/curran/.julia/packages/FileIO/e8FNK/src/loadsave.jl:118 [inlined]
 [30] main() at /home/curran/dev/honours/q6/get_class_reps.jl:49
 [31] top-level scope at none:0
in expression starting at /home/curran/dev/honours/q6/get_class_reps.jl:57
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already fixed this, but if anyone else runs into this problem, switching from `JLD` to `JLD2` fixed this for me. All that needs to be done is change `using JLD` to `using FileIO` and change all extensions in the save and load calls from `.jld` to `.jld2`.